# Is there a way to assign individual Snakemake rules their own jobscripts?

Tags: cluster-computing, snakemake

Say I have two Snakemake rules within the same workflow, with different environment/memory requirements. Outside of Snakemake, I would submit two different jobs to the cluster with different options specified depending on the needs of the job. Is there a way to specify different jobscripts for different rules to replicate this within a Snakemake pipeline?

Comment: Yes, this is mentioned clearly in the docs: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v5.1.4/executable.html#cluster-execution

Comment: Are you referring to setting the parameters (e.g. params: runtime="4h")? I am unsure how this would work with different options e.g. I want to use -pe for one rule but not another. I will rephrase my question. 

The job submission wrapper seems close to what I need, but honestly I do not understand its explanation.

Comment: Have you looked into [`--cluster-config`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v5.1.4/snakefiles/configuration.html#cluster-configuration)? If it doesn't help, showing your code and your snakemake command would help better understand the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty strings can be used for options that you want to toggle on and off for different rules.

```
rule one:
  params:
    pe=""

rule two:
  params:
    pe="-pe sharedmem 4"
```

And at the command line:

```
snakemake --cluster "qsub {params.pe}"
```